# Cannot install phantomjs2 on Openshift

Tags: npm, phantomjs, openshift

I have a free account at [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) and can succesully install [`phantomjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs) with

```
npm install phantomjs
```

This will install version 1.9.8 but since the required WebKit version is only in 2.0 I would like to have [`phantomjs2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs2)

I've tried

```
npm install phantomjs@2.0.0
npm install phantomjs2
npm install phantomjs2-ext
npm install phantomjs2.0
```

as found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=phantomjs2) but I always end up with `Install exited unexpectedly`, something like:

```
npm ERR! phantomjs2.0@1.0.2 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs2.0@1.0.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs2.0 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs2.0
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-504.34.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/opt/rh/nodejs010/root/usr/bin/npm" "install" "phantomjs2.0"
npm ERR! cwd /var/lib/openshift/563a42c289f5cffe020002f2/app-root/data/imgs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```